# Need to execute dynamic SQL query with more than 4k char

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to execute a SQL query which has more than 4000 characters in it.

I am using following code to do this:

```
create Table #sqlquery (querystring nvarchar(MAX))

declare @len nvarchar (MAX)

insert into #sqlquery (querystring) values('select * from TableA')
insert into #sqlquery (querystring) values('Where ID =3')

SELECT TOP 1  
   @len = STUFF ( ( SELECT ' ' + r.querystring  FROM #sqlquery AS r  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'), 1,1,'' )FROM #sqlquery

exec sp_executesql  @len
```

Even when I defined `nvarchar(max)`, it is truncating the last characters.

Comment: Maybe try it with text type,but nVarchar(max) will store a billion characters or so.

Comment: Don't believe `Print` statement

Comment: It is storing data! even while printing length it shows value greater then 4000, but while printing text it limits it to 4000 char.

Comment: Yes. Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms176047): "A message string can be up to 8,000 characters long if it is a non-Unicode string, and 4,000 characters long if it is a Unicode string. Longer strings are truncated. The varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) data types are truncated to data types that are no larger than varchar(8000) and nvarchar(4000)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly question, I was printing the result instead of direct executing.

Answer (score 5):

As answered by @NoDisplayName and @JeroenMostert in comments, [SP_EXECUTESQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) takes a unicode string upto nvarchar(max), but the [PRINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx) statement truncates at 4,000 unicode characters or 8,000 non-unicode.

If you want to see more of your dynamic query than PRINT will display then you could use SELECT instead. You may need to update your query options to show more output for long values.